# Convert stored procedure result to model object

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a stored procedure In my asp.net mvc3 application using Entity Framework:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MinMax
AS

DECLARE @T1 TABLE(MinColorsId int,MAXColorsId int)
INSERT @T1 
select MIN(ColorsId) as MinColorsId,MAX(ColorsId) as MAXColorsId
from DiamondInfoes 
SELECT * FROM @T1
RETURN
```

In my model I have same properties names as the procedure table result  :

```
public class colorModel
{
    [Display(Name = "MinColorsId")]
    public float MinColorsId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "MaxColorsId")]
    public float MaxColorsId { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller I run the stored procedure :

```
private _ModelContainer m_db = new _ModelContainer();
var minmax = m_db.MinMax();
```

I want to set the `colorModel` with the `minmax` that contains the procedure result? (by short way, I have many properties...)

Comment: what kind of result return m_db.MinMax()?

Comment: How have you mapped your stored procedure to your model? When importing trough the designer you can select a return type.

Comment: System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult<MinMax>

Comment: @marc_s what will I earn if I use your way?
How can I get the values?

Comment: @Hadas: you don't need that table variable at all - you have no benefit from using it. On the contrary - using a table variable put strain on your TempDB which is often already overloaded anyway....

Comment: @Wouter de Kort I selected Complex type - MinMax , How can I select MyModel type ? , It doesn't appear in the dropdownlists ?

Comment: @marc_s so???? How I continue??????????

Comment: @marc_s if you insist to know, I use .NET 4.0

Answer (score 7):

First of all, you can simplify your stored procedure to be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MinMax
AS
   SELECT  
       MIN(ColorsId) AS MinColorsId,
       MAX(ColorsId) AS MaXColorsId
   FROM dbo.DiamondInfoes
```

There's absolutely no need nor any point in having that table variable - it only puts strain on your `TempDB`.

Next - if you're on .NET 4.0 and using the database-first approach - you can import that stored procedure into your EDMX model from the wizard:

[image]

Next, go to the Model Browser in Visual Studio and find your newly imported stored procedure in the physical "store" section of your model. On your stored procedure, right-click and pick `Add Function Import`:

[image]

Now a dialog box pops up which gives you the opportunity to pick what this stored procedure returns - in your case, you said you already have a type that represents that result - so in your case, you should find this type in the dropdown for `Entities` - pick it and close the dialog:

[image]

You should now have a method on your `ObjectContext`-derived class that represents this stored procedure, and returns an entity of your chosen type.